# Why doesn't encodeURIComponent encode single quotes/apostrophes?

Tags: javascript, ajax

The **escape()** function, was deprecated and replaced by **encodeURIComponent** but **encodeURIComponent** doesn't encode single quote/apostrophe character. Which I need to escape the apostrophes in a persons surname (E.g. 'O'Neill') in an AJAX form. Why would they remove the ability of something they were trying to improve?

EDIT:

So here is a code example to explain the problem more thoroughly. So as you can see the surname 'O'Neill' contains an apostrophe that needs to be escaped when passing the variable in the url. But this would also happen in other places in the form, for instance if an address entered was 'Billy's Tavern'.

```
<input id='surname' value="O'Neill">                        
<script>
var get_url = '?surname='+encodeURIComponent($('#surname').val());
$.ajax({
    url: get_url
});
</script>
```

My current solution, using a custom function. My question was just to ask why there is a need for a custom function.

```
<script>
function customEncodeURIComponent(URI) {
    return encodeURIComponent(URI).replace(/'/g, "%27");
}
</script>

<input id='surname' value="O'Neill">
<script>
var get_url = '?surname='+customEncodeURIComponent($('#surname').val());
$.ajax({
    url: get_url
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to escape the apostrophes ? If your specific need is only that, simply do a replace.

Comment: What would they need to be escaped for?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` doesn't encode `'` characters because `'` characters don't need to be encoded in URIs.

Comment: I've edited my post with an example to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @ConTully: The question would rather be: Why doesn't your server understand query values with an apostrophe inside? They are perfectly valid and should be accepted.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`encodeURIComponent` escapes all characters except the following:

> alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

If you wish to use an encoding compatible with RFC 3986 (which reserves `!`, `'`, `(`, `)`, and `*`), you can use:

```
function rfc3986EncodeURIComponent (str) {  
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, escape);  
}
```

You can get more information on this [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

**UPDATE:**

To answer your question, on why `'` and the other chars mentioned above are not encoded by encodeURIComponent, the short answer is that they only need to be encoded in certain URI schemes and the decision to encode them depends on the scheme you're using.

To quote [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
>   correspond to characters in the `reserved set` unless these characters
>   are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
>   component.  If a reserved character is found in a URI component and no
>   delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be
>   interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that
>   character's encoding in US-ASCII.

Where "reserved set" is defined as

```
reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
            / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Apostrophe is in the `sub-delims` group.  In other words, you must leave these characters unencoded expecially if you are sure that consuming applications will know what to do with them: for example if you mistakenly encoded `?` and `&` they will no longer delimit query parts.  Historically there were also proposal for path segments parameters delimited with `;` and `,` (didn't get large adoption), so these characters are also still allowed,.  It is not that apostrohe is "free to use" (ie `unreserved`) in URI data, but that it was assumed it will have some special meaning in the URI context, for example the `segment` part:

```
segment       = *pchar
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

Comment: I've edited my post to show my current custom function, it's not as thorough as yours but uses the same idea. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: the only problem with the escape approach is that the asterisk is not encoded. This seems to work: 
    encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) { return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase(); });

Comment: Halfway this page is another copy-paste-ready example of an RFC3986 encode function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Note that in some cases, you may want to replace with `encodeURI('%27')` and not only `%27`, I just faced a bug with that. However, this answer is perfect, just what I needed

Comment: My linter tells me `escape` is deprecated. See [escape's page on MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape).

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/'/g, "%27");
```

The `/char/g` syntax tells JavaScript to replace all occurrences in your string

Comment: I'm not aware of *any* language that uses `/` as an escape character … and the question is looking for a way to programatically escape characters, not manually.

Comment: that was a typing mistake and i have updated answer..thanks for pointing out

Comment: `\ ` is not an escape character in URL encoding.

Comment: @amith, the replacement code that you provided only replaces the first occurrence of ' in the string.

Comment: the answer is updated with the custom replaceAll code..check out..does it answers your question?

Comment: You really should have a look at the [native `replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)…

Comment: but the native replace method replaces only the first occurrence.. i have tried given the flags kile g,m..its not working..it only replace the first occurrence of the character

Comment: I've edited my post to show my current custom function, it's not as thorough as yours but uses the same idea. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Bergi: yes it works.. i placed g in wrong place.. thanks dude.. and the answer is also updated with native code

Comment: there is no String.replaceAll() method.

Answer (score 4):

**Recent answer (2021)**

Using JavaScript's [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```js
console.log(new URLSearchParams({ surname: "O'Neill" }).toString())

// or

console.log(new URLSearchParams("surname=O'Neill").toString())
```

Comment: This feature has far more support in today's browsers than the date of the comment would imply. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I saw there is the same problem with the chars: `"` and `\` so that's what worked for me:

```
var replaceChars={ '\\':'\\\\' , '"':'\\"' };
encodeURIComponent(str.replace(/\\|"/gi, function(matched){
    return replaceChars[matched];
})),
```