# jQuery, apostrophes & other special characters

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8, escaping, html-encode

Using jQuery 1.9.1 in IE8 and Firefox.  Primary environment would be for IE8.

The web page I'm working on has a textarea where a user can type in text & upon a submit button click, is formatted to XML, and written to a table via an AJAX POST. It calls a stored procedure which accepts XML input.

I've tried several different ways, but can't get the following text to not throw an error when the stored procedure tries to write it to the table.  The text is:

> jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects,
>   widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.
>   Whether you're building highly interactive web applications or you
>   just need to add a date picker to a form control, jQuery UI is the
>   perfect choice.

The stored procedure says it has `"incorrect syntax near 're'"`.

I've tried 3 ways to encode the contents of the textarea, but all do the same thing & throw the same error.

I have tried:

```
encodeURIComponent( texareaMsg );
encodeURI (textareaMsg);
```

and also

```
htmlEncode(textareaMsg);
```

(where htmlEncode is the following function)

```
function htmlEncode(value) {
    return $("<div />").text(value).html();
}
```

It doesn't appear that any of them are escaping/encoding the apostrophe.  The encodeURIComponent returns:

> jQuery%20UI%20is%20a%20curated%20set%20of%20user%20interface%20interactions%2C%20effects%2C%20widgets%2C%20and%20themes%20built%20on%20top%20of%20the%20jQuery%20JavaScript%20Library.%20Whether%20you're%20building%20highly%20interactive%20web%20applications%20or%20you%20just%20need%20to%20add%20a%20date%20picker%20to%20a%20form%20control%2C%20jQuery%20UI%20is%20the%20perfect%20choice.

The encodeURI returns:

> jQuery%20UI%20is%20a%20curated%20set%20of%20user%20interface%20interactions,%20effects,%20widgets,%20and%20themes%20built%20on%20top%20of%20the%20jQuery%20JavaScript%20Library.%20Whether%20you're%20building%20highly%20interactive%20web%20applications%20or%20you%20just%20need%20to%20add%20a%20date%20picker%20to%20a%20form%20control,%20jQuery%20UI%20is%20the%20perfect%20choice.

the htmlEncode function returns:

> jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects,
>   widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.
>   Whether you're building highly interactive web applications or you
>   just need to add a date picker to a form control, jQuery UI is the
>   perfect choice.

How are you supposed to encode/escape things like the apostrophe in this case (and other special characters) that is causing this problem?  Again - I have to develop for the primary environment of **IE8**.  What I've found thus far hasn't worked.

**EDIT**

@Krishna's comment helped point me in a direction that I was able to get it working to some degree.  I haven't been able to blow it up with the test data yet. Not sure if it is the best solution either.

```
var myString = msgArr[0].MsgText;
myString = myString.replace(/ & /g, "&amp;");
myString = myString.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
myString = myString.replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
myString = myString.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
myString = myString.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

then later on when I needed to put that into the XML I was creating, I did this:

```
myXML.find("Msg").text( encodeURIComponent(myString));
```

I say it's probably not the best solution, because without putting a space in the replace for the ampersand(&), it corrupted other replacements in the string.

Comment: encodeURIComponent doesn't encode alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )..good info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251399/why-doesnt-encodeuricomponent-encode-sinlge-quotes-apostrophes)

Comment: Your problem seems more server side than client side. You seem to be vulnerable to SQL injection. Anything you can do client side won't prevent that. Rely on stored procedures or use prepared statements with parameters to store your data.

Comment: @jbl - I am calling a stored procedure that accepts 1 parameter (XML).  I can execute the stored procedure if I edit the text & replace the apostrophe with `&apos;` - however, if I do that in the web page, it breaks the AJAX POST (unexpected end of input).

Comment: maybe you should post the code that calls the stored procedure, as well as the sp itself

Comment: @Krishna - your response helped to point me in a direction that I can get it working to some degree.  See the **EDIT** in the post for what I did.  Not sure if it is the best solution, but I've not been able to break it yet.

Comment: @steve_o - nice to see it helped. why not take it a step further & write a generic way of replacing instead of trying to replace each special character. Check out my answer, it might help.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use regex for a generic way of replacing special characters using `escape`

```
var myString = msgArr[0].MsgText;
myString.replace(/[!'()*&"<>]/g, escape);
```

For example:

`"you're".replace(/[!'()*&"<>]/g, escape)`

Output: `"you%27re"`