# AJAX value %27 results in 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, tomcat, tomcat8

There are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow regarding apostrophes in form fields; mostly about unencoded values.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251399/why-doesnt-encodeuricomponent-encode-single-quotes-apostrophes) is an incredibly insightful post on why encodeURIComponent(str) does not work for apostrophes and how to create your own custom

```
    function rfc3986EncodeURIComponent (str) {...
```

The problem I have is that even when I encode the apostrophe (%27) for a value in an AJAX call from JavaScript, I get a 403 Forbidden error.  The return from Tomcat (8.5) is immediate.  It seems that there is no application processing on the Tomcat server (both the application log and catalina.out show no activity).

./application/processSomeAction.action?encodedValue=abc%27  **Results in a 403 Error.**

./application/processSomeAction.action?encodedValue=abc%2a  **Processes fine.**

./application/processSomeAction.action?encodedValue=abcd  **Processes fine.**

The AJAX call is pure JavaScript, no JQuery.

Are RFC 3986 sub-delimiters simply not allowed in AJAX calls?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible that it "all happens in the Chrome browser", as Chrome doesn't make up request codes (although it might returned *cached* responses). What does the Network Tab show? Opening up the Network Tab will show the actual request+response and can disable caching (there is an option for it, anyway).

Comment: Thx user2864740.  Edited question to state, "no application processing on the Tomcat".

Comment: Why not simply send a bare `'` character? Do you have a web server in front of Tomcat? Or a WAF, etc.? Is there anything in your Tomcat logs *other* than the access log? Meaning... can you even prove that Tomcat sees the request? I can't get my Tomcat instance to return a 403 when adding a request parameter containing a "%27" in the value (from e.g. `wget`).

Comment: Thx Chtistopher.  The problem occurred initially with an unencoded apostrophe.  We then tried encoding the apostrophe and the same problem persisted.  Please note, this problem happens in the  context of an AJAX call.  The code above follows "xmlhttp.open("POST", "..."  You are right. I do not know for sure if the Tomcat server even sees the request.  All I know is that the Network tab in the Chrome DEV tools shows a 403 status at the line in my JavaScript where "xmlhttp.send(null);" is called.

Comment: My initial suspicion was that there was something in the Chrome browser that was generating the 403 status because an apostrophe is a "sub-delimeter" according to RFC 3986 and Chrome was forbidding my request because I did not have a pair of these delimiters.

Comment: Note:  The "Time" column on the DEV Tools Network tab does show a "Request/Response" time to the Tomcat server.

Comment: Tomcat itself will not return a 403 due to this request. It's more likely due to something else like your application or some other library/framework/whatever deciding that the quote is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a proxy server restriction; nothing to do with Chrome, Tomcat or JavaScript.  Apologies for not tracking down the answer sooner.

Siteminder agent by default (built-in) checks for the 3 most vulnerable cross-site scripting characters:
Less than sign, Greater than sign, and single quote (apostrophe)
< > ‘